# How to create viewport in fabric.js

Tags: html, canvas, viewport, fabricjs

How to create an visible area, a window to a bigger object (for creating a scrollable view) using canvas and preferably, using fabric.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the easiest approach would be to just create a very large canvas object (larger than your window), and place it inside a parent container. Set the parent container's dimensions equal to the size of your desired window, and then declare `overflow: hidden;` on the container.

Once that's setup, you can probably use something like jQuery's `draggable` to handle the mouse events. If that doesn't work, the key idea is that you need to modify the canvas' `position` attribute, or adjust the `margins` to simulate panning around the canvas within the window.

This approach of course is intended for finite canvas sizes. If you want to offer an infinite work area, you would probably be better off modifying the `context.translate` property of your canvas. I imagine this would not play well with fabric.js, however.

Comment: I feel this should be part of the Fabric.js library. Example: https://github.com/rstgroup/fabricjs-viewport.